# JavaFX2.x Rectangle rounded corners are not shown

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, rectangles

Just a little problem, but I don't know how to fix it and Papa google couldn't help either.  I am drawing a rectangle with `javafx2` and I want to have rounded corners.  However the rectangle is shown with all the properties, except the rounded corners.
Here is my code:

```
   rectPasse = new Rectangle();
   rectPasse.setTranslateX(-160);
   rectPasse.setTranslateY(-160);
   rectPasse.setWidth(54);
   rectPasse.setHeight(140);
   rectPasse.setArcWidth(5);
   rectPasse.setArcWidth(5);
   rectPasse.setFill(Color.RED);
```

later on I add the rectangle to the stage:

```
   screensController.getChildren().add(rectPasse);
```

Like I said, it is shown perfectely, just no rounded corners.
If you know why, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a simple typo, you set the arc width twice:

```
rectPasse.setArcWidth(5);
rectPasse.setArcWidth(5);
```

Instead, you should set both the arc width and height:

```
rectPasse.setArcWidth(5);
rectPasse.setArcHeight(5);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help guys.  It finally works, but I have to set the arc width before I set the arcHeight.  I have to check which version of the javafx jar I have and if there is a bug involved.  Well, at least something is strange.  But none the less - Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Replace the second

```
rectPasse.setArcWidth(5);
```

With

```
rectPasse.setArcHeight(5);
```

`5` is too small value to notice,`10` or more will be better.

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
    // bevel
    rect.setArcHeight(15);
    rect.setArcWidth(15);
```